# jQuery return all content except particular element

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html;

```
<div class="modal-body">
                        <p>
                            <img class="img-responsive col-xs-6" style="float:left; margin-right:10px !important;" src="/images/someimage.jpg" /> <span>content</span> <br />
                        </p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to return the content of the `div` element without the inner `img` tag. I've tried numerous different combinations using the `not` function and also the `not:` selector, and nothing I try seems to work.

This is what I currently have:

```
var description = $(this).find(".modal-body").not("img").html();
```

I've also tested this in various browser consoles, to no avail;

```
$(".modal-body").not("img");
$(".modal-body > p").not("img");
$(".modal-body > p").not("> img")
$("div.modal-body > p").not("> img")
```

I've tried narrowing down my main Selector call, `filter()`, and various combinations of `not()`, and `not:()`.

Comment: `var content = $('.modal-body').clone().find('img').remove().end().html();`

Comment: @dfsq works perfectly, thanks. Don't really understand why it works, and why what I was doing doesn't, but it's a good starting point for me to figure it out.